# Map gremlin projection results

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

Imagine an item can be tagged by connecting unique `tag` nodes to a `post` with the twist that tags come from different sources. The source is recorded on the connecting edge, and there may be only one edge between a post and tag corresponding to the same source.
This query returns posts and their tags with the tag containing details of source and score:

```
  project('title', 'tags').by('title').
    by(inE().as('rel').
      hasLabel('tags').project('value', '_rel').
        by(outV().hasLabel('tag').values('value')).
        by(project('score', 'source').
            by('score').by('source')).
      group().
        by(values('value'))
          
    )
```

The result is in the following shape:

```
[
  {
    "title": "x",
    "tags": {
      "dog": [
        {
          "value": "dog",
          "_rel": {
            "score": 5,
            "source": "user"
          }
        }
      ],
      "cat": [
        {
          "value": "cat",
          "_rel": {
            "score": 3,
            "source": "user"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": "cat",
          "_rel": {
            "score": 2,
            "source": "google"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Question is: how can this shape be transformed to the more compact form below?

```
{
  "title": "x",
  "tags": [
    {
      "value": "dog",
      "_rel": [
        {
          "score": 5,
          "source": "user"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "value": "cat",
      "_rel": [
        {
          "score": 2,
          "source": "google"
        },
        {
          "score": 3,
          "source": "user"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is a typescript (and Neptune) implementation so some limitations apply.

A minimal sample graph is available at [https://gremlify.com/khvizyzeqg](https://gremlify.com/5igsdwlrbi) and below:

```
  property(single, 'value', 'cat').addV('tag').
    as('2').
  property(single, 'value', 'dog').addV('post').
    as('3').
  property(single, 'title', 'x').addE('tags').
  from('1').to('3').property('score', 3).
  property('source', 'user').
  property('value', 'cat').addE('tags').
  from('1').to('3').property('score', 2).
  property('source', 'google').
  property('value', 'cat').addE('tags').
  from('2').to('3').property('score', 5).
  property('source', 'user').
  property('value', 'dog')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This first answer isn't quite what you asked for because the format doesn't exactly match the example you presented, however I think it's worth considering as usable since it offers a more compact data structure with the same content and the Gremlin is quite readable:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('post').
......1>   project('title', 'tags').
......2>     by('title').
......3>     by(inE().hasLabel('tags').
......4>        group().
......5>          by('value').
......6>          by(project('score','source').
......7>               by('score').by('source').
......8>             fold()))
==>[title:x,tags:[cat:[[score:2,source:google],[score:3,source:mobius]],dog:[[score:5,source:mobius]]]]
```

This second answer produces output that should match your requested output, but as you can see it forces you to destructure the `Map` above just to re-write it back to match the form you wanted:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('post').
......1>   project('title', 'tags').
......2>     by('title').
......3>     by(inE().hasLabel('tags').
......4>        group().
......5>          by('value').
......6>          by(project('score','source').
......7>               by('score').by('source').
......8>             fold()).
......9>        unfold().
.....10>        project('value','_rel').
.....11>          by(keys).
.....12>          by(values).
.....13>        fold())
==>[title:x,tags:[[value:cat,_rel:[[score:2,source:google],[score:3,source:mobius]]],[value:dog,_rel:[[score:5,source:mobius]]]]]
```

Comment: thank you Stephen, this works.
a little detail for js/ts users - `keys` and `values` are represented in js variant by `process.column.keys` / `process.column.values`.

Comment: as a clarification, when you say "but as you can see", do you mean there's some negative side to it (e.g. performance?)

Comment: the negative is that it introduces what looks to me to be an unnecessary additional transformation (negative: extra processing) which makes the base query that gets all the data you want slightly more complicated to understand (negative: less readable).

Comment: I see. The format is dictated by a prior decision (I had another version of the query that simply looked up backwards from the tag to the original post, which produced the same result, but for tags that have 78000 posts ran into a timeout), and also by the fact that .value is not the only thing to expose, so there needs to be a "tag" level above the "_rels".

Comment: sounds like you have a good reason for the choice then, so the negatives in this case don't really matter all that much.